# Is there an example of one picture painted by different painters?

Tags: cultural-history

s there a (famous) example of the same art work created by different painters? I mean the following situation: painter X starts a painting, painter Y continues the same painting, and painter Y finishes it. What is the final result? Mix of styles? The homogeneous work looking like a product of a single artist? Anything else?

Comment: This is normal for artistic workshops.  I think *everything by Bernini* is an example.

Comment: Can you bring some specific link / name of the painting so that i can locate and look at this kind of art work. So that I can be sure that at least two painters contributed to the same work.

Comment: As noted, leading artists often had a lot of helpers. Any of a number of masterpieces had multiple people contributing work on them. Just like a general contractor doesn’t build your house all by themselves.

Comment: See [this article on Rembrandt](https://www.nga.gov/research/online-editions/17th-century-dutch-paintings/essay-issues-attribution-rembrandt.html) as an example.  For many artists, it was a business, and you don't want to waste the best talent doing the boring bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you bring some specific link / name of the painting so that i can
>   locate and look at this kind of art work.

[Morning in a Pine Forest](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_in_a_Pine_Forest) by Ivan Shishkin is a fairly famous example.

[image: Утро в сосновом лесу]

> The Morning in a Pine Forest (Russian: Утро в сосновом лесу) is a
>   painting by Russian artists Ivan Shishkin and Konstantin Savitsky. The
>   bears were painted by Savitsky, but the art collector Pavel
>   Tretyakov effaced his signature, stating that "from idea until
>   performance, everything discloses the painting manner and creative
>   method peculiar just to Shishkin", so the painting is now credited
>   solely to Shishkin.

Answer (score 6):

Historically, there are thousands of paintings that were painted by multiple artists. During renaissance and baroque, art and painting was more of a craft and trade than an expression of the artists’ message  as it’s seen today. Artists had workshops with apprentices and assistants. Training included copying the master’s work and painting parts of or even the whole commissioned paintings. The goal was to create what you describe as “homogeneous”. As the signature (if existent) also didn’t necessarily mean authorship, but could also indicate origin (compare to stamps on porcelain) and the master’s approval, modern art historians  still struggle with assigning an individual work to the actual creator. (See the [Wikipedia article about Rembrandt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt) under “Expert assessments”.)

If you are looking for a more recent collaboration where the individual artists’ contributions are very visible, I recommend you research the collaboration between [Andy Warhol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Warhol) and [Jean-Michael Basquiat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Michel_Basquiat) in the 1980s.

Answer (score 0):

To name another: Rubens-Snijders-Van Dyck. source: [www.snijdersrockoxhuis.be](https://www.snijdersrockoxhuis.be/)

Comment: Good to see a new face! Is there any way you can add a bit more meat to this? Our users generally don't like to see one line answers with links. If that website were to go down tomorrow, what on there would you want our readers to know about this person?

Comment: Torre de la Parada @ Madrid-Spain, Snijders did mainly the animal figures for Rubens, who did the supervision.

Comment: please edit your answer instead of creating extra comments. I have suggested an edit to your answer (proper link).

Comment: Good stuff! I really didn't know that about Rubens. As @tum_ suggested, could you perhaps click that "edit"  link under your answer and add that content there?